# How to count today's records in SQL Server using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to count the no of records with today's date using a linq query.

I'm getting 0, but it should be 2.

Sample data

```
Id  ShopId  Fridgetemp  UpdatedDate
---------------------------------------------------
1   NULL    23.00       2019-05-27 17:11:48.0759186
2   1       11.00       2019-05-27 17:19:23.8062202
3   1       7.00        2019-05-27 18:29:59.4886314
4   1       7.00        2019-05-27 18:44:46.6347567
5   1       27.00       2019-05-28 19:12:39.0549385
6   1       7.00        2019-05-28 19:14:59.1307374
7   1       23.00       2019-05-28 19:42:11.0724320
8   1       28.00       2019-05-28 20:08:13.3121901
```

Linq query

```
private int CheckSentStatus()
{
    return _context.FridgeTemperture
                   .Where(x => x.UpdatedDate >= DateTime.Now && 
                               x.Fridgetemp > 26).Count();
}
```

Ex op - 2

Data type of `UpdatedDate` is `datetime2(7)`.

Comment: Have you debugged this to make sure the UpdatedDate value is in the correct format and timezone as DateTime?

Comment: @McNline dates have no format, they are binary values, just like ints, decimals, numerics, etc. Storing dates as strings is a serious bug

Comment: Are you specifically looking for future dates or just dates that are today?  Also are your dates saved to the DB in UTC or local time?  If local then is all the code run in the same timezone?

Comment: i want to send a alert msg max of 2 times per day so that im using whether there is more than 2 records or not

Comment: What ORM are you using? LINQ is just a query language, it doesn't generate SQL statements by itself. Are you using EF or EF Core? Different versions have different ways to deal with dates. In SQL you'd write `where cast(UpdatedDate as date)=someDate` and SQL Server's query optimizer would convert that to a range query equivalent to `WHERE UpdatedDate >=somedate and UpdatedDate<nextday`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is Wrong you should use

You were using `DateTime.Now` which is **Today's Date and current time**, so you need to use `DateTime.Today` which is **Today's Date and `00:00` in time**.

```
return _context.FridgeTemperture.Where(x => x.UpdatedDate >= DateTime.Today && x.Fridgetemp > 26).Count();
```

**Update:**

And if you want just Today's records.

```
_context.FridgeTemperture.Where(
        x =>
        x.UpdatedDate >= DateTime.Today
        && x.UpdatedDate < DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)
        && x.Fridgetemp > 26
    ).Count();
```

Comment: Might be good to elaborate on why it is wrong and the difference between DateTime.Now and DateTime.Today :)

Comment: This will return future records.

Comment: @TonyAbrams Added the Explanation.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for pointing out, I updated the Answer

Comment: I think you can get rid of the second date check if you truncate the time on the entity in the query. `DbFunctions(x.UpdatedDate) == DateTime.Now.Date`